# Base64 PNG image is blurry in Safari using CreateJS

Tags: javascript, createjs

I'm working on a CreateJS project and I have an image created from Base64 data.

The image is blurry in Safari, but fine in all other browsers.

My code :

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo...
```

For the full code, please check [this JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bernardbaker/0at4axzq/).

Comment: Just an FYI, in my Firefox 42.0, there is no image inside the box, and it looks more blurry, and slightly larger, than in Chrome or IE... could this be a little-endian/big-endian issue? I think PNG is by definition big-endian, but is your data?

Comment: Could you take a look at the jsfiddle link please? Try it in Safari.

Comment: Upon initial load of the fiddle (or a shift refresh), no image inside the box using Firefox. On subsequent refreshes (no shift-reload) the image shows up. Same behavior on Safari.

Comment: The image on the canvas appears smooth (antialiased) rather than pixellated, as how it appears outside the canvas. I'm guessing here - maybe it has to do with the conversion to bitmap before being added to the canvas.